# Show page in WordPress depending on the device people is connected

Tags: wordpress

I have a doubt about WordPress. I know that is possible to hide a page in WordPress, but I would like to know if there is some code to show this page only to mobile devices and hide it from PC.

I would like to hide the page "subir captura" because I have a button for this function, but that button doesn't work in mobile devices, so I want to use the page, but hide it from PC.

https://i.gyazo.com/b5cd9c500ddbcaaf592cd057e183e69f.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to use wordpress is mobile function like this:

```
    <?php
     if( !wp_is_mobile() ){ 
        /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think is easiest to hide it from PC. How It would be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WP Mobile Detect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/faq) plugin to accomplish a variety of different user agent tests. Use the `wpmd_is_notdevice()` conditional to test for desktops.